# Autodock vina result extraction

Tags: python, logging, terminal, config, docking

I am doing Molecular Docking using Autodock Vina and I am getting the result in a file titled as `file.log`.
Even though it looks like it works fine in terminal since I get affinity and other results, I cannot see them properly in the log file. How can I extract my file in the same format as it in terminal? I will further extract this information in Python.
The terminal code was:

```
vina --receptor receptor.pdbqt --ligand out1.pdbqt --config conf.txt --out file.log
```

[image]

[image]

Could anyone please suggest me how I can solve this problem I want to end up with a log file which includes the data has same format with terminal?

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bash
vina --receptor receptor.pdbqt --ligand out1.pdbqt --config conf.txt > my.log
```